# Is the latest version of jQuery min (3.7.1) vulnerable to ReDoS?

Tags: jquery, security

I have been using latest version of jquery.min.js (3.7.1).

As per our security testing it vulnerable to ReDoS,

```
RegExp() called with a `t` function argument, this might allow an attacker to cause a Regular Expression Denial-of-Service (ReDoS) within your application as RegExP blocks the main thread
```

It is a latest version has many references to the RegExP taking variable regex instead of hardcoded expression like `A=new RegExp("^"+t+"$")`. Is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: Question: are you running jquery on the back-end? (server-side)  or on the client?

Comment: I think the operative word here is: _"might"_. JQuery is used in many websites, if this really was a problem, you'll be able to find it. If I look for: "redos jquery", I can find a problem with a plugin called "jquery-validation", which has been patched, but I can't find anything with JQuery itself. Note that you didn't tell us what kind of "security testing" you did. It was probably just some kind of scanning software? That can be useful for a first scan, but it can't really say anything definitively. In other words: It could miss the real problems in your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Im using jQuery for the front-end, not on the server side.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware We tested with semgrep. Yes, I see the patches for jQuery-valiation not for jQuery. If you could  see that `new RegExp("^"+t+"$")` as it doesn't have hard coded regex the tool finds out ReDos. I'm not sure jQuery validating regex before using it.

Comment: So your hacker will be breaking... their own browser... seems like it's irrelevant.

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy I assume it does, because otherwise, if it is an actual problem, people would complain about it. The jQuery Validation Plugin probably has this problem when validating form input, and that's bad because it can affect functionality. Of course the remark made by freedomn-m makes a lot of sense as well.